# TastyPie obj create method not being called

Tags: django, tastypie

Am a newbie in TastyPie. I have a very simple resource and am overriding the obj_create method in following way.

Ajax Call :-

```
 var data2 ={
                  "crave": data1,
                  "uid": "100",
                  "access_token": "AAA"                     
              };                                                   
              $.ajax({
                  url: "http://localhost:8000/restapi/v1/icrave/",
                  type: 'POST',                     
                  data: data2,
                  contentType: 'application/json',
                  dataType: 'json',
                  success: function (res) {
                      console.log(res);
                  },
              });
```

In the resource

```
class IcravesResource(ModelResource): 
person = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'person')
class Meta:

    queryset = Icrave.objects.filter(anonymous_or_not = False,is_active = True).order_by('-datetime')
    resource_name = "icrave" 
    allowed_methods = ['get','post']
    authentication =  GetAuthentication()     
    authorization = GetAuthorization()      

def obj_create(self,bundle,request=None, **kwargs):                
        print "Check if code reached here !!!"

        return super( IcravesResource, self ).obj_create( self, bundle, request, **kwargs )
```

The code is not reaching here. What am i doing wrong ? I have checked the authorization and authentication they are both returning true. How can I debug this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Python Debugger. ( http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html )

Find your copy of tastypie (possibly in your virtualenv), open the file *resources.py* and find the method *post_list*. This is the method that gets called when a POST request to a list-resource URL is send to Django.

You'll find a call to *obj_create* somewhere in that method. Now you can set a breakpoint by adding the lines:

```
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
```

in that method. Maybe as the first statement.

Now, when you start your devserver and issue your ajax-call the execution should stop at the set_trace() and you should see a python prompt in the shell you did start the devserver.

Now you can explore the runtime-environment of the request.  You can can for example inspect local variables by entering them at the prompt.
You can see the listing of the method you're in by typing '**l**' (little L), execute the next line with '**n**', step into a function with '**s**'.

This should help you make sense of what is happening. Take some time to learn how to use pdb, it's well worth it.

For more info on pdb and django, see:

http://ericholscher.com/blog/2008/aug/31/using-pdb-python-debugger-django-debugging-series-/

Comment: It seems there was a error in the JSon format that was being posted to the view. After endless hours of debugging. I found that the raw post data i.e. request.raw_post_data was Json format but for some reason request.POST was not. Which was causing the error. As the subsequent methods in the Tasty pie wanted json formating. I changed that with some difficluty. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify based on the server logs, that the server actually got the POST request?

If so, you can also try specifying the allowed methods list, by putting:

```
list_allowed_methods = ['post', 'get']
```

instead of general `allowed_methods` one.

Here is a code snippet, which worked for me:

```
class EntryDetailsResource(CommonResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = Entry.objects.all()
        detail_allowed_methods = ['put','get','delete']
        list_allowed_methods = ['post', 'get']
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
        validation = EntryDetailsValidation()

    def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
        import sys
        print sys.stderr, 'aa'
        return super(CommonResource, self).obj_create(bundle, request, user=request.user)
```